# gRPC Server - maximum number of executor threads reached

Tags: multithreading, grpc-java

I have implemented a gRPC server which has just only one RPC method. It takes the input object (contained in the request) and write synchronously it into an Apache Kafka topic thanks to the Kafka clients producer API. I have set as **executor** a *fixed thread pool* of 50 threads.

Suppose that Kafka brokers are not available due to a temporary fault and the gRPC server receives so many requests such that all the 50 threads to handle them become busy since they are all blocked due to the synchronous write retries for the Kafka topic.

- What does it happen if other requests arrives while all the 50 threads are busy?
- Does the gRPC queue them safely? Is there a risk to lose some request?
- Do you know where this concept might be described in the official documentation?

Thank you very much.

P.s: Kafka is just an example I used to explain the question, you can think of any other service which requires a synchronous write.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using C++. I'll also preface this answer by saying that the C++ synchronous API for gRPC is not very performant. The async API is what is generally recommended for performant code.

Yes, those bytes would get queued up in the transport layer. To enforce limits on how many bytes would get queued up, please configure ResourceQuota [1]https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/6a10e41db75bd6074bf01a08d260365e44922f04/include/grpcpp/server_builder.h#L222
[2]https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpcpp/resource_quota.h

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'm actually using Java. Do you know if it's the same?